# how to sort a vector in the order it is read from file with structures

Tags: c++, vector, structure

I have a structure  with names and grades inside, I will use a vector which is meant to read the inside of a file till the end with the structure. For example:

```
 struct ReadAll{string name; double numbers;}

 vector <ReadAll>userInfo;
```

i need to display the results in a file so far everything works but i need to display them as ex: student1 89 47 99.... student4 89 78 45.. but all i get is student4 98 78 45 ... student1 89 47 99..   how can i display them in the right order?

```
void writeStudents(vector<Student>& students, string outputFileName)    
{//students.push_back(Student());

ofstream outputFile;
outputFile.open(outputFileName.c_str()); 
while(students.size() != 0) 
{

   for (int count = students.size(); count > 0; --count)
   {  
      students.back().average = (students.back().grade1 + 
      students.back().grade2 + students.back().grade3) / 3; 
      outputFile << "size is: "<< students.size() <<endl;
      outputFile << students.back().name <<endl;
      outputFile << students.back().grade1 <<endl;
      outputFile << students.back().grade2 <<endl;
      outputFile << students.back().grade3 <<endl;
      outputFile << "Average: " << students.back().average <<endl;
      students.pop_back();
      //count++;
   }
 }
```

}

As it is now I just dont see what I have to do.

Comment: What is the definition of `Student`?

Comment: What is 'the right order'. It's not at all clear from your question.

Comment: student is the actual name of the vector ex: vector<Student>students;

Comment: the right order would be student1 grade, grade grade, student2 grade, grade grade, student3 grade, grade grade, and so on but i get it all backwards lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there anything wrong with the easy way of doing things? Something like this

```
for (int i = 0; i < students.size(); ++i)
{
    outputFile << students[i].name <<endl;
    outputFile << students[i].grade1 <<endl;
    outputFile << students[i].grade2 <<endl;
    outputFile << students[i].grade3 <<endl;
}
```

I don't understand why you are going backwards through the vector and removing items as you print them. That's a bit strange.

Comment: i did that before and i was getting an error but it seems like i was doing it wrong .... i  love u so much right now

Answer (score 0):

Generally, the C++ way of doing things is far simpler:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& outputFile, const student& stud) {
    outputFile << stud.name << '\n';
    outputFile << stud.grade1 << '\n';
    outputFile << stud.grade2 << '\n';
    outputFile << stud.grade3  << '\n';
    outputFile << "Average: " << stud.average <<'\n';
    return outputFile;
}

void writeStudents(vector<Student>& students, const string& outputFileName)    
{    
    std::ofstream outputFile(outputFileName.c_str()); 
    for (int count = 0; count <students.size(); ++count) //why the complexity here?
    {  
        //this line seems like it shouldn't be in a "write" function
        students[i].average = (students[i].grade1 + 
                students[i].grade2 + students[i].grade3) / 3; 
        //This line seems out of place
        outputFile << "size is: "<< students.size() <<'\n'; 
        outputFile << students[i]; 
    }
}
```

Or, if you had calculated the averages before calling writeStudents, then it's simpler still:

```
void writeStudents(const vector<Student>& students, const string& outputFileName)    
{    
    //open a file
    std::ofstream outputFile(outputFileName.c_str()); 
    //write number of students 
    outputFile << "size is: "<< students.size() <<'\n'; 
    //copy all of the students to the output file
    std::ostream_iterator<Student> oiter(outputFile)
    std::copy(students.begin(), students.end(), oiter); 
}
```

Comment: thx a lot mooning.. the community of this site is awesome i will try to answer some questions myself.. entry level questions of course